# Sending email in asp.net via local host server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any example that can explain me to send email from my localhost server ?
I've written this example but it doesn't work the error is **"Failure sending mail".**

```
 SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
        smtpClient.Port = 25;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mostang1970@yahoo.com", "secret");
        smtpClient.Send("mostang1970@yahoo.com", "hadinematipartow@yahoo.com", "Let’s eat lunch!", "Lunch at the Steak House?");//here is the error
```

And what should i do in web.config?

Comment: Do you have SMTP configured on localhost ?

Comment: you are using localhost and using credentials from yahoo, I don't think this will work

Answer (score 24):

Here ya go :)
[localhost-with-aspnet-without-smtp-server](http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2010/01/27/testing-email-from-localhost-with-aspnet-without-smtp-server/)

Let me please know if it works for you the way you need it to.

---

Link above doesn't work, so I'll improve the answer.

For testing purposes we can use localhost like this: [How to Test Email Without Configure SMTP in ASP.NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/how-to-test-email-without-configure-smtp-in-Asp-Net/)

In case the link goes down again, basically we have to modify web.config like this:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Mails\"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

and C# code

```
  MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
  MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("mail@mail.com");
  mailMessage.From = fromAddress;
  mailMessage.To.Add("mail@mail.com");
  mailMessage.Body = "This is Testing Email Without Configured SMTP Server";
  mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
  mailMessage.Subject = " Testing Email";
  SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
  smtpClient.Host = "localhost";
  smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

This will output a file to our desired directory.

Comment: Sidenote: The `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage` is now deprecated. You can use `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the settings for your SMTP server in web.config. There are several example online (e.g. [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/11/17/mailsettings-smtp-network-windows-2008-web-server.aspx))

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="test@mydomain.com">
            <network host="smtp.mail.com" userName="name@mydomain.com" password="pwd" port="25"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Then you can simply use the SmtpClient class to send:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("recipient@email.com");
msg.Subject = "test";
msg.Body = "test body";

smtpClient.Send(msg);
```

Comment: You don't need any extra SMTP server... ;)

Comment: I agree if it's installed on localhost. what about if you are using an external provider (e.g Rackspace)?

Answer (score 2):

here is the sample:

```
public static void SendMailMessage(string from, string to, string bcc, string cc, string subject, string body)
{
    // Instantiate a new instance of MailMessage
    MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();

    // Set the sender address of the mail message
    mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
    // Set the recepient address of the mail message
    mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));

    // Check if the bcc value is null or an empty string
    if ((bcc != null) && (bcc != string.Empty))
    {
        // Set the Bcc address of the mail message
        mMailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc));
    }      // Check if the cc value is null or an empty value
    if ((cc != null) && (cc != string.Empty))
    {
        // Set the CC address of the mail message
        mMailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc));
    }       // Set the subject of the mail message
    mMailMessage.Subject = subject;
    // Set the body of the mail message
    mMailMessage.Body = body;

    // Set the format of the mail message body as HTML
    mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    // Set the priority of the mail message to normal
    mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

    // Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient
    SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    // Send the mail message
    mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
}
```

And call the function:

```
SendMailMessage("fromAddress@yourdomain.com", "toAddress@yourdomain.com", "bccAddress@yourdomain.com", "ccAddress@yourdomain.com", "Sample Subject", "Sample body of text for mail message")
```

Comment: I got `System.InvalidOperationException: The SMTP host was not specified.`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 bool ret = true;

            try
            {
                string _smtpServer = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["appEmailHost"];

                Web.Mail.Mail mail = new Web.Mail.Mail(_smtpServer,         
        System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Html, System.Web.Mail.MailPriority.Normal);
                mail._From = test@test.com;
                mail._To = Test2@test.com;
                mail._Subject = subject;

                mail._Body = body;
                mail.SendMail();
                ret = true;
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                _GravaErro(exp);
                ret = false;
            }

            return ret;
```